# Retrieve records inserted with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am using `accept_nested_attributes` to save records. I want to access ids of the child records created. 
  e.g. `params[:client]` has `subscriptions_attributes` coming as `nested_attributes` from the form. `Client` `has_many :subscriptions`. 
  When I'll call `@client.save`. It will save `client` as well as `subscriptions`. I want to access the `ids` of the subscriptions inserted.

One solution I have is to collect `subscription_ids` before saving the records and then collecting again after save and then `(after_ids - before_ids)`

Is there any rails way or fool proof method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be one alternative:
You can save the time just before saving the client and then retrieve the records created after that time.
E.g.
`before_create_time = Time.now`

Then, after saving

`inserted_subscriptions = @client.subscriptions.where('created_at > ?', before_create_time)`

Comment: Thanks... reduces a query atleast...:)